# Concatenate 2 rows with different id code and menu name in SQL

Tags: sql

```
ID_code      Menu_Name      Sale    Unit_sale
4204          orange       150080     7504
4182          orange       958060     47903
4182       orange juice     140        7
2068           NULL        1398697    12508
4536           NULL         44600     1115
```

I have this table in SQL, but i want it to become like this:

```
ID_code  Menu_Name    Sale     Unit_sale
4204      orange     1108280    55414
2068       NULL      1398697    12508
4536       NULL       44600      1115
```

sum all the same menu_name as well as with the same ID_code, but then retain all the null values. How to code this? It is possible ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Already tried something?

Comment: Do you have something against orange juice?

Comment: orange juice is the same id_code with the other orange, i want to make all having with the same menu_name and same id_code and adding all together to make it one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Select ID_Code, case when cast(id_code as varchar(100))=cast(Menu_name as varchar(100)) then NUll else Menu_name end Menu_name, Sale,Unit_sale from (
Select max(ID_Code) ID_Code, case when Menu_Name like 'Orange%' then 'Orange'
when Menu_Name is null then cast(ID_Code as varchar(10))
else Menu_name end Menu_name,sum(Sale) Sale,sum(Unit_sale) Unit_sale from test
group by case when Menu_Name like 'Orange%' then 'Orange'
when Menu_Name is null then cast(ID_Code as varchar(10))
else Menu_name end)a
```

Table structure used:

```
create table test
(ID_code  int,    Menu_Name varchar(100),      Sale int,    Unit_sale int)

insert into test values
(4204,      'orange' ,    1108280,    55414),
(2068 ,      NULL     , 1398697   , 12508),
(4536  ,     NULL      , 44600    ,  1115)
```

Result Set:

```
ID_Code Menu_name   Sale    Unit_sale
2068    NULL    1398697 12508
4536    NULL    44600   1115
4204    Orange  1108280 55414
```

Comment: orange is one of my data, i have lots of them having the same menu_name and ID_code, how can i do that?

Comment: You can identify the possible related Menu_Names and put them in case or switch statement. e.g. orange & orange juice
If it becomes to tedious there are other ways to identify similar names using soundex or Levenshtein Distance algorithm.
If you identify the related menu_names then you can be sure that its 100% accurate.

Comment: sorry im only a beginner, but can you give me a codes. thanks alots.

Comment: I would suggest the simplest thing to do is write case statements like:
case when Menu_Name like 'Orange%' then 'Orange'
when Menu_Name like 'ABC%' then xyz... and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
select Menu_Name,sum(Sale),sum(Unit_sale) from table_name group by Menu_Name;
```

This can give you Menu_Name Sale Unit_sale but not ID_Code. Null Value will not be retained separately. For this you can use some coalesc function (provided in postgres) and if value is null give it some random name.